# C "RunTime Error" for UVa 1225 "Digit Counting"

Tags: c, runtime-error

I was solving an UVa problem. When checked in UVa it showed "Woohoo! Your output is identical to the accepted output!". But when i submitted the code it kept getting "Runtime error". I have no idea why is this happening or why "Runtime error happens at all."

Here is the problem -> https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=16&page=show_problem&problem=3666

Here is my code ->

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int j=0,n,num,i,a[10000],b[10],k,it,l;
scanf("%d",&it);
for(l=0; l<it; l++)
{

    scanf("%d",&n);
    j=0;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        num=i;
        while(num!=0)
        {
            k=num%10;
            num=num/10;
            a[j]=k;
            j++;
        }
    }
    a[j]=9999;

    for(i=0; i<=9; i++)
    {
        b[i]=0;
    }

    for(j=0; a[j]!=9999; j++)
    {
        b[a[j]]++;
    }

        printf("%d",b[0]);

    for(i=1; i<=9; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d",b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RunTime Error` occurring in you code is `segmentation fault` . This is because of you usage of  `a[10000]`. In your code `a[j]=k;` you are using so much of memory.*(for a 2 digit number you use 2 array locations , 3 digit 3 etc)* So for a number greater than `3000` *(approx)* You is go out of limit `10000` and results a `segmentation error`.

You don't need that `a[10000]` to implement the counting code.

Try this simplified code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, num, i, b[10], k, it, l;
    scanf("%d", &it);
    for (l = 0; l < it; l++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            b[i] = 0;
        }

        scanf("%d", &n);
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            num = i;
            while (num != 0)
            {
                k = num % 10;
                num = num / 10;
                b[k]++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d", b[0]);

        for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            printf(" %d", b[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output :-**

```
2
3
13
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 6 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked and shows me a simpler way of approach.

Comment: It would clear much more if you could explain why my code got an "Runtime error".

Comment: you code will not work for big numbers like `9999` .In those cases segmentation fault *(runtime error)* occurs

Comment: I have explained It in the answer. I think you are clear now.

Comment: Thanks. For the clarification. It helped.